# upgrade intellij JDK from 1.6 to 1.7 problem

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic

I need to upgrade JDK version of my old spring project from 1.6 to 1.7.
I use intellij 11.1.1 and weblogic 10.3.3
I've done following changes:

1. change Project SDK to 1.7 in project setting
2. change all modules SDKs to 1.7 in project setting
3. change Maven runner JRE to 1.7
4. change JAVA_HOME in windows environment variable to JDK 1.7 location
5. change both BEA_JAVA_HOME and SUN_JAVA_HOME to JDK 1.7 location in setDomainEnv.sh in my domain
6. change JAVA_HOME to 1.7 in commEnv.sh file

but still when i run project, following message is written in intellij output:

**starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode, sharing)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\bin\java -client**

I'm really confused about this problem, thanks for your help

Comment: If you going to upgrate, make sure its the last update of Java 7, if not the last version of Java 8. Note Java 11 is released this month.

Answer (score 1):

Please match your steps with these ones:

1. Install JDK 7;
2. Stop all processes that use the your MW_HOME.
3. Edit $MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/common/bin/commEnv.sh and change the
   JAVA_HOME location.
4. For every domain, change the domain "setDomainEnv.sh" script to
   accommodate for the net JAVA_HOME
5. Change the JDK location specified in nodemanager.properties for the
   default and any other existing node manager process
6. Replace the new JDK location on all the minor tools used in the same
   MW_HOME, such as BSU, uninstaller, etc.
7. Restart the processes as normal, they should take the new JDK
   version.

Also please refer to this [link](http://akhilesh-humbe.blogspot.com/2012/10/upgrade-jdk-used-by-oracle-weblogic.html) for details.

I hope it will help you to resole your problem,

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I reinstalled JDK7.I didn't found any nodemanager.properties file (i don't use cluster). I change sdk version in minor tools and removed ".IntelliJIdea11" folder and reconfig my intellij. my configs are in my new post

Answer (score 0):

**Intellij prompts:**
C:\WLMiddleware\user_projects\domains\hull\startWebLogic.cmd
The JRE was not found in directory C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_21. (JAVA_HOME)
Please edit your environment and set the JAVA_HOME

[Environment Variable config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsxfb.jpg)

**setDomainEnv file:**
WL_HOME="C:/WLMiddleware/wlserver_10.3"
export WL_HOME

BEA_JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_79"
export BEA_JAVA_HOME

SUN_JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_79"
export SUN_JAVA_HOME

if [ "${JAVA_VENDOR}" = "Oracle" ] ; then
    JAVA_HOME="${BEA_JAVA_HOME}"
    export JAVA_HOME
else
    if [ "${JAVA_VENDOR}" = "Sun" ] ; then
        JAVA_HOME="${SUN_JAVA_HOME}"
        export JAVA_HOME
    else
        JAVA_VENDOR="Sun"
        export JAVA_VENDOR
        JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_79"
        export JAVA_HOME
    fi
fi